# How do I use POST in django1.5 with TemplateView?

Tags: django

I am trying to port my app from django 1.4 to 1.5. I changed all my occurrences of:

```
return direct_to_template(request, template)
```

to:

```
return TemplateView.as_view(template_name=template)(request)
```

This works fine for all my forms that use GET, but for my forms that use POST I end up with a blank page on my browser. No error anywhere, just a blank page.

In 1.5 what do I use in place of direct_to_template for a POST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/) response class which takes the same parameters as direct_to_template shortcut. You can just replace and be safe

```
return TemplateResponse(request, template)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I had to also pass in my context. But now I'm having an issue with RedirectView. I had replaced the 1.4 occurrences of redirect_to with RedirectView.as_view, but it's blowing up in django/utils/cache.py in patch_vary_headers. It appears that RedirectView.as_view is not returning a HttpResponse, whereas redirect_to did. I'm very surprised that going from 1.4 to 1.5 is so much hassle.

Comment: Try django.shortcuts.redirect

Comment: I changed it to use HttpResponseRedirect and that's working for me.

Answer (score 3):

The [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) can be used as a replacement for `direct_to_template` for this usage. It takes the same parameters as `direct_to_template` so it can be a simple find and replace.

```
return direct_to_template(request, template)
```

becomes

```
return render(request, template)
```

Comment: render didn't work for me - I couldn't pass in a context to it. I used TemplateResponse and that's working.

Comment: The third argument to `render` is the context and it uses a `RequestContext` by default.

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't have to explicitly return a TemplateView like that, you just put it in your urls and you're done with it.

Now, the reason you don't get a response with a Post is that TemplateView only defines a GET method

So you would need to create a new class that inherits from TemplateView in order to implement a POST method yourself.

My recommendation would be to look for the other CBV and see if one matches your needs better, perhaps a FormView would suffice

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L147

Comment: This is huge app that I didn't write, but I have taken over maintenance for. I don't want to have to totally restructure it to upgrade from one version of django to another.